# What is the hex string in readlink output

Tags: linux, shell, readlink

When I run this command 'readlink /proc/3192/exe', it returns the output '/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm;62d69987 (deleted)'.

There is a hex string ';62d69987' in the output, what is it?

Comment: Most likely it was part of the filename, which may contain anything besides `'\0'` and `'/'`. How that file got created and then executed and then deleted might be more interesting.

Comment: @thrig You are right. That string is part of filename, and it created by rpm during rpm package upgrading. That suffix is the rpm transaction ID. After the content was copied from rpm archive to that temp file and verified, it will be renamed to the target name.